# How can I include multiple JavaScript scripts for buttons, pictures, etc. on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have two scripts that are conflicting. On is to have two buttons be a blueish color, another is for the webcam functionality. These are the two scripts:

How can I have the buttons script work and keep the functionality of the plugin? I'm new to jQuery so thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Look at Niklas's answer below... you must load jQuery first, then jQueryUI, then the jQuery plugins, then finally any of your custom jQuery scripts.  All of that just before the `</body>` tag is fine while leaving all the CSS includes up in the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

before

`<script src="/jquery_custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Isn't that exactly how he's doing it now?

Comment: In his post yes, but if you take a look at his source code, `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">` is one of the last bits on his page, right before `</body>`

Comment: @Niklas:  Ugh!  You are correct.  @Pete Allport, you need to move all your jQuery script plugins so they load AFTER jQuery!

Comment: @ Pete Allport before you call anything related to jQuery. To be on the safe side, put it before any other javascript and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: @Pete- look at the comment I made on your question.